# Generalizing a specific question

Tags: discussion, editing

A question asks about case A. All the answers explain the rule with respect to cases A and B which have the same rule (or at least no one has yet to find a distinction). Is it appropriate to generalize the question *post facto* to ask about A and B, or leave the question alone because it is technically perfectly fine as is?

Comment: This question could be improved by a specific example.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Actually I disagree. I think we should agree on a theory and debate its application in each circumstance. Any example I give will bias answers in a certain way. Besides, maybe no example exists yet?

Comment: Downvoter, what are you disagreeing with? That we should discuss this? I didn't take a stand in the question.

Comment: The official SE answer to this is yes. I'll see if I can find the blog post.

Comment: @HodofHod That would be quite helpful of you. (And see my above comment about 'yes' being ambiguous here.)

Comment: @HodofHod Do you know where the blog is? [Lo.Yodeya](http://lo.yodeya.com/) has disappeared

Comment: @ba I referred to the SE blog, see my answer below. As to the blog formerly at lo.yodeya, I don't know.

Comment: an example: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17977/may-one-have-augmentative-cosmetic-surgery

Comment: @Menachem I was just thinking that. Go ahead!

Comment: @DoubleAA: I just voted the older one as a dupe of the newer one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [StackExchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> The editing feature is there so that old question/answer pairs can get better and better. For every person who asks a question and gets an answer on Stack Overflow, hundreds or thousands of people will come read that conversation later. Even if the original asker got a decent answer and moved on, the question lives on and may continue to be useful for decades.
>
> [...]
>
> **It is OK to edit a question to make it more general.** With the power of editing comes the power to take someone’s selfish, very specific question, and edit it a little bit until they’re asking the more general question that hundreds of people encounter. For example, if someone asks, “I set up a web server at home but I can’t access it from work,” it’s OK to rewrite the question as, “What things should I check when a web server running at home is not visible on the Internet?” In fact, sometimes selfish, stupid questions of the “do my homework” variety can be easily edited into a form where the answer will provide an extremely valuable resource for the internet at large.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address when the answers were already given to the question (which would make the answers less applicable)

Comment: @ba Made it clearer. Please read the whole blog post.