# Changing a Question to Better Fit the Answers and For the Sake Of the Internet?

Tags: discussion, editing

As many of the mods here know, i posted a question regarding [where to buy cantillation CDs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/where-to-purchase-cantillation-cds). However, none of the answers posted answer the question, and it seems like there is a lot of content online, but that this content might be useful to others. So would it be in accordance with the rules to change the question to "Where can I find online cantillation resources for all Nusachs?" and continue to allow everyone post answers?

Answer (score 7):

As long as you don't [invalidate any upvoted answers](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759), then [generalizing a question is considered ok](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1300/759).

Indeed if all answer posts to a question answer the wrong question, it is probably better for the site to bring the question in line with the answers and post the intended question elsewhere, instead of deleting all the valuable answers. This way we get more useful, organized, helpful content.

Comment: I may be missing a concept in both your answer as well as the rules. Isn't the initial concept that members answer what's in the question, not to accommodate the question to the answers that got there?

Comment: @DanF I don't know what an "initial concept" is or why it is relevant.